# Why can I set VLC as my default browser?

Tags: macos, system-settings

I have Yosemite 10.10.2 installed; in my System Preferences > General, my default browser selection allows me to choose VLC. Why does this happen and can it be removed?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because VLC supports generic http URLs.  If you want to experiment, **proceed with caution**.

First, make a backup copy of `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/Info.plist` and put it in a safe place.

Then, using a text editor such as emacs or vi (not TextEdit.app !), remove the following lines:

```
            <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleURLIconFile</key>
                    <string>generic</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                    <string>http url</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                            <string>http</string>
                    </array>
            </dict>
```

This should be enough to convince the OS that VLC should not be used as a browser; although I don't know what (if anything) will break in VLC.  You may need to reboot in order to see the effects of the plist change as well.

If things are unstable after that, you can restore the backed up Info.plist file to `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/Info.plist` in order to return to the way things used to be.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not TextEdit?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen, because VLC can open weblinks which are both VLC and browser supported. But to switch back, just open your main browser and set that to be the default browser.

For Firefox:

- open Firefox
- open Preferences > Genereal
- and enable the checkbox to check if it is the default browser

If anything other than Firefox then becomes default browser, Firefox will ask to set this back to Firefox on the next opening. This works for Safari, Chrome as well.